# Unable to return the read the values present in an excel file

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jxl, testng-dataprovider

I want to return the values present in an excel file but it is returning values like [[Ljava.lang.String;@490ab905.  Data is not returning the values like user name. Used jxl and data provider. Even i am not aware of data provider much.  Please help me to fetch the accurate values from excel.

Following are my code:

```
public class excelUtil {

    // public String suiteFileName = "/suite.xls";
    String testDatafile = "/src/testData/testdata.xls";
    // public String testDatafile = "/testdata/Testdata.xls";

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getTestData(String sheetName)
    {



    //String getTestData(String sheetName, int rowNumber, int colNum) {
        // Read Excel

        String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + testDatafile;

        Workbook w = null;
        File inputWorkbook = new File(path);
        // Open workbook
        try {
            w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
        } catch (BiffException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Get the first sheet
        Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(sheetName);
        //Loop over first 10 column and lines
        // Get the first sheet

                //Loop over first 10 column and lines
                int rowCount =  sheet.getRows();
                int columnCount = sheet.getColumns();

                Object[][] data = new String[rowCount-1][columnCount];

                for(int i=1;i<rowCount;i++)
                {
                    Cell cell = sheet.getCell(0, i);
                    String value = cell.getContents().toString();
                    System.out.println(value);
                    data[i-1][0]= value.toString();
                System.out.println(data[i-1][0]);
                    cell = sheet.getCell(1, i);
                    value = cell.getContents().toString();

                    data[i-1][1]= value.toString();

                }
                w.close();
                //System.out.println(value);
                System.out.println(data);
                return data;
            }
    public static WebDriver driver ;
    @Test(dataProvider = "getTestData")
    public void OrpakLoginTest(Object username, Object password) {
         driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http:orpakqa.commdel.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Loginelements lg = new Loginelements();


        WebElement element_UserName = lg.getOrpakUserNameField(driver);


        element_UserName.sendKeys(username.toString());
        WebElement element_Password = lg.getOrpakPasswordField(driver);

        element_Password.sendKeys(password.toString());
        //WebElement element_LoginBtn = lg.getOrpakLoginButton(driver);
        //element_LoginBtn.click();

    }
```

Comment: try to use .toString() in your return value

Comment: hi. Shubham jain I tried the same but result is same

Comment: what is your data inside in the sheet which you want to retrieve can you post a sample data similar like same

Comment: UserName   Password   in string format

Comment: for(int i=1;i<rowCount;i++) <br/> 
    {
     Cell cell = sheet.getCell(0, i); <br/> 
     System.out.println(cell); <br/>
     String value = cell.getContents().toString();<br>
     System.out.println(value); <br/>
     data[i-1][0]= value;<br/>
     
    System.out.println(data[i-1][0]);<br/>
     cell = sheet.getCell(1, i);<br/>
     System.out.println(cell);<br>
     value = cell.getContents().toString();<br/>
     System.out.println(value);<br/>
     data[i-1][0]= value;<br/>
     System.out.println(data);<br/>
    }

Comment: in this loop the problem exist. because when i am trying to print the values. Output is jxl.read.biff.LabelSSTRecord@490ab905
namanUsr
namanUsr
jxl.read.biff.LabelSSTRecord@56ac3a89
Naman@123
[[Ljava.lang.Object;@27c20538
[[Ljava.lang.Object;@27c20538
jxl.read.biff.LabelSSTRecord@72d818d1

Answer (score 0):

Use POI Jars

https://poi.apache.org/download.html

Below code is working for me:-

```
public String getXLcellValue(String xlpath, String sheetName, int rowNum, int cellNum)
    {
        try{
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(xlpath);

        Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(fis);

        Log.info("Get the value from the cell(getXLcellValue)");

        return wb.getSheet(sheetName).getRow(rowNum).getCell(cellNum).getStringCellValue();

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.info("Error in getXLcellValue ="+ ex.getMessage());
    }
    return "";
}
```

> xlpath = path of excel file in your system
>
> Sheetname = name of the sheet in excel file
>
> row = row number of username or password
>
> cellnum = cell number of username or password

Comment: but i want to use dataprovider as well

Answer (score 0):

You can update your code as below and I hope this solution work for you:

```
import java.io.File;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ProApp extends OneClass {

    Workbook wb;
    Sheet sh1;
    int numrow;
    String username;
    String password;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void oneTimeSetUp() throws InterruptedException {

    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("Testing.com");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/main/section/ul/li[1]/a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    }

    @Test(dataProvider="testdata")
    public void testFireFox(String uname,String password1) throws InterruptedException

    {

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='username']")).clear();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='username']")).sendKeys(uname);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']")).clear();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']")).sendKeys(password1);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@name='loginButton']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    @DataProvider(name="testdata")
    public Object[][] TestDataFeed(){

    try {

    // load workbook
    wb=Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C://File//Book2.xls"));

    // load sheet in my case I am referring to first sheet only
    sh1= wb.getSheet(0);

    // get number of rows so that we can run loop based on this
    numrow=  sh1.getRows();
    }
    catch (Exception e)

    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Create 2 D array and pass row and columns
    Object [][] logindata=new Object[numrow][sh1.getColumns()];

    // This will run a loop and each iteration  it will fetch new row
    for(int i=0;i<numrow;i++){

    // Fetch first row username
        logindata[i][0]=sh1.getCell(0,i).getContents();
    // Fetch first row password
        logindata[i][1]=sh1.getCell(1,i).getContents();

    }

    // Return 2d array object so that test script can use the same
    return logindata;
    }

    }
```

Comment: Also add jxl jars in your project library. And make sure your Excel shoudl be Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet with extension .xls   for example Testdata.xls